# date calculation showing 5 weeks date Range format DD/MM/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY is not working in tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculation, dateadd

I have requirment showing data in colunms 5 week data from 2020-2021 in tableau.I am trying below calculation its fetching only 1 week data not 5 week data.so that data is mismatching.

```
     '''
     'STR(YEAR(DATETRUNC('week',[Statsday (copy)])))+"/"+ 
     STR(MONTH(DATETRUNC('week',[Statsday (copy)])))+"/"+ 
     STR(DAY(DATETRUNC('week',[Statsday (copy)]))) '
    '+ " - " +'   
    'STR(YEAR(DATETRUNC('week',DATEADD('week',5,[Statsday (copy)]))-5))+"/"+
     STR(MONTH(DATETRUNC('week',DATEADD('week',5,[Statsday (copy)]))-5))+"/"+
     STR(DAY(DATETRUNC('week',DATEADD('week',5,[Statsday (copy)]))-5))'
     '''
```

Comment: please try to add some sample input/output data in order to get a better understanding of your need

Comment: I need to show 5 week data in columns like this date ranges.
Output: 2021/8/1 - 2021/9/5 2021/7/25 - 2021/8/29 2021/7/18 - 2021/8/22

My code to show the date range not working properly.That only gving out put for 1 week values even it displays 5 week date range.

Comment: What is all the string manipulation here about? Tableau works happily with dates without any need to do elaborate messing about with strings.